# Angular JS w/ http.get( ) + Cross Site Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to request data from a local .json file in my angular application using http.get( ) but am running into (what I have just learned as) a cross-site validation (XVal) problem. I am not familiar with this and other cross-site validation questions don't quite seem to be clear. I have at least learned the issue is most likely solved by tweaking the local server...but I have no idea where to start in that realm. My app currently works on plunker (my actual project file system is essentially the same): http://plnkr.co/edit/ny95zv?p=preview
How could I go about "tweaking my local server if this is how I am using http.get?

```
var app = angular.module('scattChartApp', ['nvd3'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('chartdata.json').success(function(response) {
      response.options.chart.tooltipContent = function(key) {
         return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>';
      };
      $scope.options = response.options;
      $scope.data = response.data;
  });


});
```

Comment: I had the same issue. I didn't want to install so many files on my PC just to have a server running, so I just downloaded a virtual machine software and installed a Apache server on it. That's the easiest way I think if you want to test locally.

Comment: I have a Debian VM and installed apache via the command:
aptitude install apache2

Answer (score 0):

You can not request data from a static directory (i.e. `file:///path/to/your/directory`. To solve this `cd` to your app directory and use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. If you have a mac, python should be installed automatically.

Alternatively you can also download `simplehttpserver` via npm and execute the `simplehttpserver path/to/your/directory` command.

You can also use a chrome extension to get by this-- check out the extension called Allow-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Ok so something weird is happening. I installed http-server and used the command...but now only the chart title is displaying "Scatter Plot Example"